# How to change the sender's email using SMTP in Laravel4?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I want to change the mail sender in Laravel Framwork and I tried this:

```
$message->from('new@example.com , 'new' );
```

But it doesn't work well. The sender's email is still the **username** we defined in the config file ( app/mail.php).

How can I change from the default sender from the mail.php to the different sender's emails?

Comment: The way you are trying to change the mail address seems perfectly fine and is working for me. Which smtp service are you using?

Comment: It is smtp.gmail.com

Comment: $message->from('new@example.com , 'new' );
It overrides the : 'from' => array('address' => "user@gmail.com", 'name' => "user") in mail.php.
But it will be replaced by the Username in mail.php ('username' => "user@gmail.com")

Comment: gmail is the problem, not laravel. You need to setup gmail for sending from different email addresses. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en

Comment: I'd recommend using mandrill instead https://mandrill.com/ 12.000 emails free per month, no stress

Comment: Hello michael! 
It still make errors if I use other SMTP in my mail.php, for example smtp.allweb.com.kh.


Error: Expected response code 220 but got code "500", with message "500 5.3.3 Unrecognized command "

Comment: 500 Merans server unavailable, so there Seems to be something wrong with the Settings. Check ssl or tls settings too, depending on your SMTP service.

Comment: Thank so much michael for your answers and recommendation. I'm newbie on this.